# WPF repeater control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have the following working code:

```
<StackPanel>
      <TextBlock FontSize="14" Foreground="White" Text="Case Type: " TextDecorations="Underline"/>
      <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding CaseType, Converter={StaticResource MyEnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static order:CaseTypeEnum.TypeA}}"
                   Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}" 
                   Content="{Binding CaseType, Converter={StaticResource MyEnumDescriptionConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static order:CaseTypeEnum.TypeA}}" />
      <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding CaseType, Converter={StaticResource MyEnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static order:CaseTypeEnum.TypeB}}"
                   Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}" 
                   Content="{Binding CaseType, Converter={StaticResource MyEnumDescriptionConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static order:CaseTypeEnum.TypeB}}" />
      ...
      ...
      ...
      <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding CaseType, Converter={StaticResource MyEnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static order:CaseTypeEnum.TypeJ}}"
                   Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}" 
                   Content="{Binding CaseType, Converter={StaticResource MyEnumDescriptionConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static order:CaseTypeEnum.TypeJ}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Is there any way to do the same functionality without copy/paste :)

Comment: create an `ItemsControl` with it's `Itemtemplate` as the `RadioButton`. Have all entries of your enum put into a collection property like `ObservableCollection<CaseTypeEnum> SomeProperty` and bind your `ItemsControl.ItemsSource="{Binding SomeProperty}"`.

Comment: @Viv May you help me more?

Comment: sure what is `CaseType` and is it the same for each of the `RadioButton`'s? and my guess is your converter with it's parameter tweaks it accordingly?

Comment: - CaseType is an Enumeration.

- Yes, It's the same for each RadioButton.
 
- MyEnumToBooleanConverter is a IValueConverter to check the current value of CaseType (the binding property) and returns true/false.

- MyEnumDescriptionConverter is another IValueConverter to read the DescriptionAttribute for each enum member.

Comment: CaseType is a property of type CaseTypeEnum :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok without knowing your logic I cannot validate if you actually need two values going into the converter where 1 is the same for every item anyways.

However assuming you indeed do need them:

xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
      <local:MyEnumDescriptionConverter x:Key="MyEnumDescriptionConverter" />
      <local:MyEnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="MyEnumToBooleanConverter" />
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <RadioButton>
          <RadioButton.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyEnumDescriptionConverter}">
              <Binding Path="." />
              <Binding Path="DataContext.CaseType"
                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                        AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
            </MultiBinding>
          </RadioButton.Content>
          <RadioButton.IsChecked>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyEnumToBooleanConverter}">
              <Binding Path="." />
              <Binding Path="DataContext.CaseType"
                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                        AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
            </MultiBinding>
          </RadioButton.IsChecked>
        </RadioButton>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Starting from the Top:

`Items` is defined as:

```
public List<CaseTypeEnum> Items {
  get {
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(CaseTypeEnum)).Cast<CaseTypeEnum>().ToList();
  }
}
```

and

```
private CaseTypeEnum _caseType;
public CaseTypeEnum CaseType {
  get {
    return _caseType;
  }
  set {
    if (value == _caseType)
      return;
    _caseType = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => CaseType);
  }
}
```

enum:

```
public enum CaseTypeEnum{
  TypeA,
  TypeB,
  TypeC,
  TypeD,
  TypeE,
  TypeF,
  TypeG,
  TypeH,
  TypeI,
  TypeJ,
}
```

As for the two `MultiBinding`'s, I just put some dummy code like

`MyEnumDescriptionConverter` -

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
  if (values.Length < 2)
    return string.Empty;
  return string.Format("Formatted {0} with CaseType property: {1}", (CaseTypeEnum)values[0], (CaseTypeEnum)values[1]);
}
```

and `MyEnumToBooleanConverter`

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
  if (values.Length < 2)
    return false;
  return ((CaseTypeEnum)values[0]).ToString().EndsWith("D");
}
```

which should when run give you:

[image]

You can download the sample **[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/thbielkb930wo57/MvvmLight29.rar)**

Comment: Excuse me, but why we use MultiBinding?

Comment: @m.samy cos `ConverterParameter` cannot take a Binding.

Comment: I have a problem at MyEnumToBooleanConverter. If CaseType property changed it does't update the UI.

Comment: @m.samy It works fine for me in the example I attached to the answer. You need to check your INPC implementation to verify property changes being propagated to the UI(Updates not coming to the UI is almost always a case of wrong INPC implementations or usage) . Create a new question(with that as the topic) if you still can't figure it out than reuse the same thread.